# Cannot trigger macro when clicking on a shape any more (powerpoint)

Tags: powerpoint

I have attached a macro to a shape with a simple hello world message. It did work a few days ago then now it doesn't work any more in the same ppt file.

Any reason and how to restore normal behavior ?

Comment: 1. there's not enough information here to be able to help you troubleshoot directly. can you replicate the issue with another slide deck, etc.? 2. at 63% acceptance, most people won't want to answer your question because you don't pick an answer to your questions. based off of your other threads, if something doesn't answer your question, rephrase it or state why and provide more information.